Bounding two quadrilaterals with a tight Quadrilateral
I am in search for a function $f$ which can figure out a tight bound of two given quadrilaterals with a quadrilateral. An illustration of this is given in the figure below

By tight bound, I mean minimizing the area $\text{area}(\square S_1S_2S_3S_4) - area(\square P_1P_2P_3P_4 \cup \square Q_1Q_2Q_3Q_4) \ge 0$. Given quadrilaterals are never self intersecting. My thoughts:

This problem is similar to Minimum bounding box algorithms, but I have not seen one which consider a tight bound problem like this one over a quadrilateral. If one requires a bounding box, then taking $x_{\text{min}}$,$x_{\text{max}}$,$y_{\text{min}}$,$y_{\text{max}}$ we can construct a box and be done.
This problem can be realized as a constraint problem. Defining the function $g : \mathbb{R}^{8} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$ g(S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4) = \text{area}(\square S_1S_2S_3S_4) - area(\square P_1P_2P_3P_4 \cup \square Q_1Q_2Q_3Q_4) $$ we would like to minimize $g$. But since intersections are allowed, I am not sure how to implement the constraint that quadrilateral $S_1S_2S_3S_4$ is bounding the other two quadrilaterals.


This problem is expressed more simply by realizing it is equivalent to find a minimum quadrilateral enclosing an octagon. You can see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11580/minimum-area-bounding-quadrilateral-algorithm

It might be a hexagon depending on how the given quadrilaterals are overlapping. But I can how this realization makes the problem easier. @caduk

If we for now assume that none of the four edges of the quadrilaterals overlap (we have an octagon) how do I get the vertices of this octagon? In the figure above,  It is, $P_1Q_1Q_2P_2P_3Q_3Q_4P_4$, but in general how do we figure out this ordering? @caduk

You can compute the convex hull (using for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan)
